# Edit PDF to prevent casual printing

Tags: pdf, printing

I am trying to edit a PDF to prevent users from casually printing it. I would like to do this without spending money. I know that this isn't very secure, but we just need a basic solution.

I have tried [PDF Rider](https://pdfrider.codeplex.com/) but it keeps saying that the document is already locked and the settings are greyed out. Are there any other good, free tools or methods for doing this?

Comment: What about setting a password for the pdf?

Comment: @Sunny Setting A password is greyed out in Adobe Acrobat

Comment: @David - Have you asked your network Administrator to enable it?  You have to set a `Security Method` in order to do this with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @Sunny As mentioned below, Adobe Acrobat is asking me to spend money when I try to set the protection using the Tools menu. I would like to do this for free if reasonably possible.

Comment: @David: Are you using the free Reader? If so, you can't set security settings. You need Acrobat Standard or Pro in order to do that. There may be other applications which can do it, but they won't be free either. And if you consider programming it using one of the libraries floating around, you spend way more time (and money) to accomplish this.

Comment: @David - There is no way that Adobe Acrobat is asking for "money" Adobe Acrobat has this feature enabled out of the box.  You are clearly using Adobe Reader not Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: @Ramhound Right, I have the reader. I always get those two mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sejda.com can [protect your PDF file from being printed](https://www.sejda.com/encrypt-pdf) for free as well.

[image]

Upload your PDF file. 
Click the "More options" button. 
Make sure the Allow: "Printing" is unselected 
Click "Encrypt"

Done! Download your result.

Answer (score 1):

From Adobe:

> At the top right in Acrobat, click the Tools pane. Open the Protection panel.
>   Click Encrypt, and select Encrypt With Password. Confirm that you want to change the security of the 
>   document.
>   The Permissions password restricts printing, editing, and copying based on your selections.

Click OK and save.
This should work, and for people you want to print it, you can give them the password.

I think [FoxyUtils](https://foxyutils.com/protectpdf/) can also do this for free.

Comment: When I click on this in Adobe Acrobat DC, it redirects me to a page asking me to spend money. I would like to do this for free.